# Form input and save multiple records in a hasMany through model

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakephp 2.6

I have set up 3 tables as follows (simplified):

A ‘people’ table with id, fname, lname, phone…
A ‘skills’ table with id, skillname.
A ‘people_skills’ table with id, person_id, skill_id, score

I have  18 skills listed in the skills table, such as Legal, IT, Fundraising, etc., and a user can have a score of 1, 2 or 3 for each skill.

I believe the models are set up correctly, as I can do a $this->PeopleSkill->find(‘all’) and my view happily shows a table with the correct rows of the person’s name, a skill name, and their score for that skill.

I’m trying to create a form that shows one person and lists all 18 skills, with radio buttons by each skill for the scores 1, 2 or 3, to quickly fill in a score for every skill for 1 person.

The submit would write 18 lines to the database, each line would have the person_id (same for all), one skill_id, and the corresponding score for that skill.

I’m new to cakephp and the form/mysql magic still sometimes eludes me, which just makes me want to revert to raw php loops and mysql calls. But I think learning the cake way will be better.

My current failed experiments have me looping through a skills list and trying to build a form line by line, but I’m pretty sure I’m completely going the wrong direction with that, since getting the form right should make the save action easier.

Tonight I’ve been looking at the saveMany method, but I’m lost how to build the form to create the appropriate array for that, and then how best to save it. Do I need to create some sort of saving loop?

If you need to see parts of my model, controller or view, just let me know and I’ll happily share whatever you'd like to see.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: please put in some code you have tried so far.

Comment: is the result of that are all inserts or a mix of inserts and updates to the MySQL?

Comment: If cakephp's magic can make it easy to insert OR update, like in some of my simpler forms, that would be great, but to start with I'd be happy just to be able to all inserts. I've added my current controller and view code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I assume People and Skills are added

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('PeopleSkill');
$score_list = array(
'1' => '1',
'2' => '2',
'3' => '3'
);
foreach($skills as $key => $skill) {
    echo $this->Form->hidden('PeopleSkill.'.$key.'.person_id',array('value'=>$person['Person']['id']));
    echo $this->Form->hidden('PeopleSkill.'.$key.'.skill_id',array('value'=>$skill['Skill']['id']));
    echo $this->Form->input('PeopleSkill.'.$key.'.score',array('type'=>'radio','options'=>$score_list,'legend'=>$skill['Skill']['name']));
}

echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

In your controller

```
$this->PeopleSkill->saveMany($this->request->data['PeopleSkill']);
```

For Updating the skills

In your controller

```
public function customadd($directorid = null) {

if($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->PeopleSkill->saveMany($this->request->data('PeopleSkill'))) {
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}

$testdate = date('Y-m-d');
$this->set('testdate', $testdate);

$person = $this->Person->findById($directorid);
$people_skills = $this->PeopleSkill->find('all',array('conditions' => array('person_id' => $directorid)));
$this->set(compact('person'));
$this->set(compact('people_skills'));
}
```

In your view

```
Current Person : <?php $person['Person']['name']; ?>
<?php
$scorelevel = array(
    '1' => '1',
    '2' => '2',
    '3' => '3'
    );

echo $this->Form->create('PeopleSkill');

foreach ($people_skills as $key => $skill) {
    echo $this->Form->hidden('PeopleSkill.'.$key.'.id',array('value'=>$skill['PeopleSkill']['id']));
    echo $this->Form->hidden('PeopleSkill.'.$key.'.person_id',array('value'=>$skill['PeopleSkill']['person_id']));
    echo $this->Form->hidden('PeopleSkill.'.$key.'.skill_id',array('value'=>$skill['PeopleSkill']['skill_id']));
    echo $this->Form->input('PeopleSkill.'.$key.'.score',array('type'=>'radio', 'options'=>$scorelevel,'legend'=>$skill['Skill']['skill'],'value'=>$skill['PeopleSkill']['score']));
}
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This gets me much further. I needed to change the last 'hidden' to 'input', or I just got an empty screen.

On the first form input line, I changed `$person['Person']['id']` to `$skill['Person']['id']` to solve an error where $people was undefined. I think that worked, but perhaps I should just set the $people variable in the controller.

That may be related to my other problem, and that is about setting all these scores for 1 person. If I set $skills in the controller with `$skills = $this->PeopleSkill->find('all')`, then my form shows me multiple repeated skills. If in the controller is set $skills with `$skills = $this->PeopleSkill->find('all',array('conditions' => array('person_id' => $directorid)))`, having passed the person id as $directorid, then I get a form showing only the skills already entered for that person, with none selected, and submitting them adds a whole set of duplicate entries.

For now I'm okay with not being able to edit previous data, if I can indicate a specific person id and get a complete set of skills in the form and submit them all as new, that would be great.

For your reference, here are my controller and view files.

Controller

```
public function customadd($directorid = null) {
    $testdate = date('Y-m-d');
    $this->set('testdate', $testdate);

    $skills = $this->PeopleSkill->find('all',array('conditions' => array('person_id' => $directorid)));
    $this->set('skills', $skills);
    $this->set('directorid', $directorid);

        if ($this->PeopleSkill->saveMany($this->request->data('PeopleSkill'))) {
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
```

And the view

```
<?php
$scorelevel = array(
    '1' => '1',
    '2' => '2',
    '3' => '3'
    );

echo $this->Form->create('PeopleSkill');

foreach ($skills as $key => $skill) {
    echo $this->Form->hidden('PeopleSkill.'.$key.'.person_id',array('value'=>$skill['Person']['id']));
    echo "[Debug] Current peson is: ".$skill['Person']['fname'];
    echo $this->Form->hidden('PeopleSkill.'.$key.'.skill_id',array('value'=>$skill['Skill']['id']));
    echo $this->Form->input('PeopleSkill.'.$key.'.score',array('type'=>'radio', 'options'=>$scorelevel,'legend'=>$skill['Skill']['skill']));
}
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
// print_r($skills);
?>
```

This yields a form showing only the skills that already a value filled in in the database.